# No Sound on Debian

Tags: debian, audio

I've been dabbing around with LinuxMint Debian and i'm not getting any sound.
Have removed Pulse = still no sound.
Re-installed it, still no sound.

Basically the only sound i get is when i perform the test with the Logitech headset.
Otherwise, no sound anywhere.

Have also tried an experimental version of LM Debian KDE but same story.

Anyone else in a similar predicament?

Here are my laptop's specs on Windows 7 .32bit :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7j0l0odzn07vq0o/Screenshot%20-%20System%20Info.jpg